# Update value of a global variable with a variable inside in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, scripting-language

How can I update a variable which has inside a variable and keep it global?

I know I can do this to update a variable but which isn't global:

```
for i in {1..24}; do 
    query=query_$i
    echo $query
done
```

I want to do something like this:

```
query=query_$i

for i in {1..24}; do
    echo $query
done
```

The variable doesn't update.

Comment: Unless you're in a function and have explicitely declared your variable local, then updating its value will be visible for the whole shell the value has been updated in. I would expect a `echo $query` after your first loop to output `query_24` (see [here](https://ideone.com/nKsjRH) if not convinced), isn't that what you want?

Comment: Would you do this in any other language? Why do you feel the need to do it in `bash`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you need to do this. If it's a quiz, one way I can think is to run `query` as a command inside "for" loop:

```
query='echo query_$i'                                                                                                      

for i in {1..24}; do                                                                                                       
    eval $query                                                                                                            
done
```

Comment: No. It isn't a quiz. It's ignorance. The need is for queries to a database where parameters change.